# Update in nested select in MySQL does not work when executed repeatedly

Tags: mysql, select, nested

I got this answer from a query posted on the site. It works well the first time around so I accepted the answer but now it does not do so if executed repeatedly!  The update column is referenced only once so why would it not work when executed the second time around. The T1.col1 is assigned UNIX time in the real situation. Also, I do not understand the role of t11 in the from list.

```
       update T1 join
             (select max(col3) as maxcol3
               from T1 t11
               where col2 = 12345
             ) tmax
                on T1.col3 = tmax.maxcol3 and
                   T1.col2 = 12345
        set T1.col1 = 500;
```

Comment: `t11` is an `alias` - aliases are used to give temporary names to columns, tables or expression results. For example if a self-join is needed, you cannot do `... FROM table JOIN table ON table.col1=table.col2` because `table` is ambiguous (which table? 1st or 2nd?). You must use an alias: `... FROM table JOIN table AS alias ON table.col1 = alias.col2`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen the second time?  The value of `col1` is already set to `500`.

Comment: Thanks! Gordon. I was hoping you would respond. The value of col1 is already set to 500. True. But the MySQL rowcount() function should still return 1 or greater than zero with no other db activity. It is returning zero. No syntax error. When I change the value of 500 (which actually is UNIX time), I do get sometimes unpredictably (or may be I did not notice the pattern) a row count > 0